# PHP OOP - MySQL connection from within a class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place, but it seems that as my questions are rather conceptual, it's harder to browse for related opened topics.

Anyway, here's the issue: I own a small e-commerce company (in Brazil) and I need to track all my shipments in one place and i want to be aware of possible delays and other events that take place with the products my company ships, according to my own criteria.

The Post Office provides something like an API and I have already managed to retrieve all information about each event related to a shipment.

I have created a database in which i have, among others, two tables: One for the shipment itself (tracking code, destination and some other stuff) and another for all events that take place.

I have also created two classes, that corresponds to these two tables: One is called shipments an the other events (obviously). I believe that there's no need to create this second table, as everytime i load the page the events are loaded from the Post Office Website, however, and this is my first question, i believe my script will run a lot faster if it doen't need to retrieve all this data from the internet everytime, am I right? Besides that, I figured that using the database makes it easier to process this data using MySQL queries. Does that make any sense?

The third and most important question is about the implementation of the methods of these classes. When the script runs, it retrives data from the shipments table and I'm not sure whether to connect and retrive this information from within (inside) the shipment class itself, or if i should connect from the outside and just provide the class with the results of my queries and then let it do the rest.

I figured that connecting to the database from the shipments class makes it less flexible (I don't believe that this should be handled there), however, it seems, at first, a lot easier to create a method inside the class that connects to the BD, loops through the results (querying other table's data to calculate how many days from now to the deadline), instantiating itself (from within the class) and returning an array with the objects for further manipulation. Does this make any sense??

I really can't figure out which one is the "correct" option.

I'd apreciate if someone could help me out with that.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is regarding your third question ...

I think you should implement a separate layer (you can say it another class) as far as your data retrieving is concerned ..the reason being , it will be easily maintainable and scalable in the future ( for eg retrieving data from the above mentioned class and using it in another class for reporting purpose) and your shipment class should only implement the business logic which you are applying on the data retrieved through the above mentioned class. So In this way you have build two separate layers one is model layer and other is controller ( which somewhat follows the mvc approach ) and in my view this would be the right approach to design the system.

Comment: Thank you very much man. I knew that connecting through the class wasn't the way to go, but I needed to hear it from someone else.

Comment: Thank you very much man. I knew that handling all this stuff through the class wasn't the way to go, but I needed to hear it from someone else. 

About this layer, should it be specificly created to give support to a particular class (like shipments), or could it be more generic? I already have a class that handles db stuff and yet another, that acts somewhat like the layer you've suggested, but I have a feeling that maybe I could extend it to offer a more specific support for each class. Would it be too much specialization?

Anyway, thank you very much. U've already been extremely helpful.

Comment: I think its alright as long as it can be extended and its method can be reused time and again. And in future if you have to scale your system ,You never know which one of your systematically designed class can help you out.